# RV / Manufactured Home Toilets Adapter

Tags: plumbing, toilet, rough-in, adapter

Situation: I'd like to eventually upgrade my toilet from a cheap, manual flush (need to physically apply foot pressure) to an affordable one that has a "walk away" flushing mechanism. It doesn't matter to me whether the unit is designated for "RV" or not, there seems to be plenty of small 10" toilets available. The [rough-in size](https://www.lowes.com/projects/bed-and-bath/toilet-buying-guide1/article) for mine is 8 1/2". It seems the smallest ["UniFit" rough-in adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005XNVH4C)  would expand the rough-in to at least 10".

Question: Perhaps there are rough-in adapters for a 8 1/2" rough-in available on the market? If it's safe to use "UniFit" adapter, what should the installer keep in mind?

Comment: Changing the toilet and flange is just one side, what are you connecting the flange into.  ABS pipe or direct to a tank?

Comment: @spicetraders Abs pipe.